# C to Rust and back "pointer being freed was not allocated" on Rust side

Tags: c, rust

I'm trying to call some Rust code from C and get a result back, but I'm getting a "pointer being freed was not allocated" error on the Rust side.

I want to call the `hex::encode` function. I pass in a pointer to some bytes, the length, and a pointer allocated in C with malloc. I want the result of the conversion passed back at this pointer.

The Rust function:

```rust
extern crate libc;

use hex;
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::os::raw::c_char;
use std::vec::Vec;
use std::{ffi, ptr, slice};

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn bytes_to_hex_string(bp: *mut u8, bp_size: usize, sp: *mut c_char) -> i8 {
    println!("1");

    let p_vec = unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(bp, bp_size, bp_size + 1) };

    println!("2");

    let str = hex::encode(p_vec);

    println!("3");

    let bytes = str.as_bytes();

    println!("4");

    let cs = CString::new(bytes).unwrap(); // will fail if bytes has "gap" (null) in sequence

    println!("5");

    unsafe {
        libc::strcpy(sp, cs.as_ptr());
    }

    println!("6");

    return 1;
}
```

Called from this C code:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int8_t bytes_to_hex( uint8_t *, unsigned int, char *);

int main() {
  char *ptr = "Hello World!";
  char *hex = (char *)malloc(1000);
  printf("about to call....\n");
  bytes_to_hex_string((uint8_t*)ptr,strlen(ptr),hex); 
  printf("about to print....\n");
  printf("%s\n",hex);
  printf("about to free....\n");
  free(hex);
}
```

When I run the program:

```
$ ./a.out
about to call....
1
2
a.out(2941,0x7fffccae03c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x10afe2b80: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

It looks like the Rust code inside the hex crate is freeing the `ptr` pointer, is that right?

Is there a way round this somehow? I would prefer for the allocation and freeing to happen in C, but I am open to any suggestions to solve this!

Comment: From the documentation on [`Vec::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts): _"`ptr` needs to have been previously allocated via `String`/`Vec<T>` (at least, it's highly likely to be incorrect if it wasn't)."_ Generally, it is meant to be used as a way to recover a `Vec` that was previously disassembled/forgotten, not as a way to create vectors from an arbitrary memory buffer. As the answer suggests, turning these raw parts into a slice is most likely the right way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want Rust to deallocate your pointer, don't use types that own the allocation. `Vec` and `CString` both take ownership of the pointer and manage it. Presumably you were surprised to need to provide both a length and a capacity?

Use [`slice::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html) instead:

```
extern crate libc;
extern crate hex;

use std::ffi::CString;
use std::os::raw::c_char;
use std::slice;

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn bytes_to_hex_string(bp: *mut u8, bp_size: usize, sp: *mut c_char) -> i8 {
    let p_vec = slice::from_raw_parts(bp, bp_size);

    let str = hex::encode(p_vec);
    let cs = CString::new(str).unwrap();

    libc::strcpy(sp, cs.as_ptr());

    return 1;
}
```

I didn't test this, so I cannot say if your `strcpy` is correct. Panicking in a FFI function is undefined behavior, however. It's also surprising that you declare both pointers as mutable... You also don't need to import `Vec` as it's in the prelude.

See also:

- [Slice arguments in *The Rust FFI Omnibus*](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/slice_arguments/)

Comment: It worked. And I made the first pointer const, like you said. I didn't know some types manage and others don't. A lot to learn for rust :( Many thanks.